# Data table returning the column name rather than the value

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio, datatable

I'm using a MySQL database to populate a data table. I want to print/display the values from two columns of a given record, mealID and madedate. I'm able to retrieve the first column, mealID and display it although for madedate, it displays the column name instead of the actual value.

If I swap the order of mealID and madedate around in the SQL statement, I can retrieve madedate but not mealID so there's an issue with that second column or how I'm retrieving it.

```vb
            Dim mealStockData As DataTable

            Dim mealName As String
            Dim madeDate As String


            mealStockData = (connClass.runAdapter("SELECT `mealID`, 'madedate' FROM `tblMealStock` WHERE mealStockBarcode='" + Me.txtScanIn.Text + "'"))
            'madeDate = mealStockData.Rows(0).Item("madedate").ToString()
            madeDate = mealStockData.Rows(0)("madedate").ToString


            mealName = (connClass.runAdapter("SELECT `name` FROM `tblMeal` WHERE mealID=" + Str(mealStockData.Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()))).Rows(0).Item(0).ToString()

            MsgBox(mealName)
            MsgBox(madeDate)
```

Here's the connection class where I run the adapter to populate the data table:

```
    Function runAdapter(sqlcommand)

    Dim adapter As New MySqlDataAdapter(sqlcommand, conn)
    Dim table As New DataTable
    adapter.Fill(table)
    Return table

    End Function
```

[image: Message box saying 'madedate' when running the program]

Comment: I've realised the issue now. I've used 2 different quotation marks in the SQL statement. The slanted ones used to wrap mealID are the ones required. Tested and now working.

Comment: please use prepard statements with parameters, so that it diesn't matter

Comment: I believe this code is vulnerable to SQL injection. Would you mind fixing it?

Comment: This is just a snippet of the code to demonstrate how I'm retrieving those 2 values. I've got strict input validation and error checking to prevent any harmful injection.

Comment: Why bother with writing code to prevent SQL injection when you can just do it the proper way and use parameters and be guaranteed that it can't happen?

Comment: The Microsoft way of escaping identifiers is to wrap them in brackets, e.g. `SELECT [ColumnName] FROM [TableName]`. I don't think that MySQL supports that in general but Connector/Net does explicitly add support for the Microsoft parameter prefix, `@`, so it might support brackets too. They aren't inherently better than graves - that's what those symbols are actually called; it's an accent used in French - but they are a bit more readable, so that can be a bonus.